# Subdomain constraints and url helpers on a domain with a subdomain (sub-subdomain?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing, subdomain

So I have read all about how to use Rails 3 subdomain constraints and url helpers, which works great for most applications.  For instance, if I want an admin subdomain (which I do) I can use:

```
constraint :subdomain => :admin
  scope :module => :admin
    defaults :subdomain => 'admin'
```

But my application runs on many (customers') domains, and usually on a subdomain of it.  So, something like `directory.customer.com`.  Now if I apply that logic to `admin.directory.customer.com`, Rails things `directory` is part of the subdomain, so I have to do this:

```
constraint :subdomain => /^admin.*/
  scope :module => :admin
    defaults :subdomain => 'admin'
```

This is great, just match any subdomain that stats with admin, BUT when it comes to using the url helpers, it's NOT great, because the default subdomain I've set (`admin`) doesn't include the customer's portion of the subdomain (`directory`).

Setting the :host option to `directory.customer.com` doesn't seem to fix this, the url helper still returns `admin.customer.com`.  Is there any way to set it up so url helpers "know" that the `directory.customer.com` is all part of the :host and the subdomain shouldn't overwrite that part of the host name?  There's got to be a method I can modify or something to make it keep that host name intact, right?